# Do while loop for Try again program not working correctly (java)

Tags: java

I created a program that convert text to ASCII value and now when i press Y to try again and input a new string there will be a error that string is out of range etc.

I am new in this field, I will appreciate your help.

And here is the Error

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 17,length 17
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkIndex(String.java:3278)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.charAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:307)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuffer.charAt(StringBuffer.java:242)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:26)**

```
    package com.company;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            boolean Flag;  // The Boolean variable for the do while lopp
            int n,l,j=0,m,i,ch;
            char t;
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {


                    System.out.println("Enter any string and it will convert into numbers:- ");
                    data.append(input.nextLine());
                    l = data.length();
                    m = l;
                    System.out.println(l);

                    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                        t = data.charAt(j);
                        n = (int) t;
                        System.out.print(n);
                        System.out.print(",");
                        j++;
                    }
                data.delete(0, m-1);

                System.out.println("\nDo you want to try again? Y/N");
                ch = input.nextInt();
                //Those are the condition for that the program should be run again or not
                if (ch == 'Y' && ch == 'y')
                    Flag = true;
                else if (ch == 'N' && ch == 'n')
                    Flag = true;
                else
                Flag = false;
            }
            while(Flag=true);
            System.out.println("Thanks, Come Again");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may also find that unless you want people to enter "89" to try again, you should use `input.nextLine().charAt(0)` to get input (or just `input.nextLine()` and use `equalsIgnoreCase`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n,l,j=0,m,i,ch;
```

This declaration is invalid. If all of these values are supposed to be
0, the declaration should look like:

```
int n, l, j, m, i, ch = 0
```

Also your logic in the nextInput section is incorrect.

```
    if (ch == 'Y' && ch == 'y')
        Flag = true; 
    else if (ch == 'N' && ch == 'n')
        Flag = true; 
    else
        Flag = false;
```

Instead of the AND ( && ) this should be an OR ( || ).  If it's 'Y' OR it's 'y'. It will likely never be both Y and y. This should be fixed as follows:

```
    if (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y') { 
        Flag = true; 
    } else if (ch == 'N' || ch == 'n') {
        Flag = false;
    }
```

Also, as mentioned by @Stultuske, you'll want to change your while condition to:

```
while (Flag == true)
```

One thing that's niggling at me here is that ch is an integer, but you're asking it if that value is 'Y, y, N, n' those are characters and not integers. I'm guessing that's why you got the 'Input_Mismatch_Exception'. Hope this helps.

Edit: Formatting

Comment: Thanks Kalea, I have changed the logic to logical OR after running the program.

Comment: Could you tell me when i press Y and then try to input a new string there is a error that the string is out of the range, so can you tell me how to clear string each time when user try again the program

Answer (score 2):

```
while(Flag=true);
```

this doesn't check whether the value of Flag is true, it sets it to true, and thus automatically returns true.

What you want is:

```
while(Flag==true);
```

or,

```
while(Flag);
```

for short.

You may also want to read up about naming conventions.

As for your Exception:

Y is not an int, change your

```
ch = input.nextInt();
```

to

```
ch = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

this will solve the initial problem, but still might lead to false results with unexpected input (or lack there of)